# Svelte: Images loaded in batch not being called from the right build path

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have the following Svelte 4 component, with some images loaded by batch from a specific folder (and one image loaded normally just for reference):

```html
<script>

    import ImageThatWorks from "$lib/images/singles/image.jpg"

    const imagesBlob = import.meta.glob(`$lib/images/batch/*.{png,jpg}`)
    const imagesUrl = Object.keys(imagesBlob)

</script>

<div> 
    <img src={ImageThatWorks} alt='Image that works' width='300' />
    <div class="photogrid">
        {#each imagesUrl as imgUrl}
            <img src={imgUrl} />
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

When running in dev mode with `npm run dev` (a script that runs `vite dev`), all images displays properly, since, as far as I understand, vite loads assets from their original locations in dev mode.

**When  building (with `npm run build`), images are successfully copied in the assets folder (`dist/assets`). Then, when running the build with `npm run preview`, only the single reference `ImageThatWorks` is displayed and called from `dist/assets`. The other images loaded in batch are not displayed and still called from their original location (`src/lib/images`).**

**Why? How should I manage images when loaded by batch?**

*Side question: what's the best way to load also their thumbnail version within the same batch?*

Here is the vite config file for information:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  base: './',
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    assetsDir: 'assets'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      $lib: path.resolve('./src/lib')
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte(),
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the glob import is used is wrong. The keys of the record give the path that was used to import, not the *result* of the import.

Also, you would want to use the `eager` option, otherwise all imported modules have to be asynchronously awaited.

It should be this:

```js
const imageModules = import.meta.glob(
    `$lib/images/batch/*.{png,jpg}`,
    { eager: true },
);
const imageUrls = Object.values(imageModules).map(module => module.default);
```